# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension when trying to install Rails / Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't install rails and I have no idea why. It gives me this error when building native extensions - it seems to be related to Nokogiri, but I've installed all its dependencies and it still does it. Trying to install Nokogiri separately does the same thing where it fails at building. No idea what to do at this point. Any help appreciated!

```
  ☣ ~$ gem install rails
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200629-95634-19o1vmg.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.10
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch
    - 0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch
    - 0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch
    - 0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch
    - 0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.10... OK
Running git apply with /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/patches/libxml2/0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/patches/libxml2/0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/patches/libxml2/0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/patches/libxml2/0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.10 (from /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ports/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libxml2/2.9.10)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.34.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxslt/1.1.34... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.34 (from /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ports/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libxslt/1.1.34)...
checking for -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./html_document.h:4,
                 from html_document.c:1:
html_document.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
html_document.c:16:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   16 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "0*", &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
html_document.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling html_element_description.c
compiling html_entity_lookup.c
compiling html_sax_parser_context.c
compiling html_sax_push_parser.c
compiling nokogiri.c
compiling xml_attr.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_attr.h:4,
                 from xml_attr.c:1:
xml_attr.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_attr.c:61:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   61 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &name, &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_attr.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_attribute_decl.c
compiling xml_cdata.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_cdata.h:4,
                 from xml_cdata.c:1:
xml_cdata.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_cdata.c:23:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   23 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &doc, &content, &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_cdata.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_comment.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_comment.h:4,
                 from xml_comment.c:1:
xml_comment.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_comment.c:21:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   21 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &content, &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_comment.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_document.c
xml_document.c: In function ‘dealloc’:
xml_document.c:49:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘rb_st_foreach’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   49 |   st_foreach(node_hash, dealloc_node_i, (st_data_t)doc);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         int (*)(xmlNode *, xmlNode *, xmlDoc *) {aka int (*)(struct _xmlNode *, struct _xmlNode *, struct _xmlDoc *)}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/intern.h:39,
                 from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2148,
                 from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_document.h:4,
                 from xml_document.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/st.h:141:31: note: expected ‘int (*)(st_data_t,  st_data_t,  st_data_t)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘int (*)(xmlNode *, xmlNode *, xmlDoc *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct _xmlNode *, struct _xmlNode *, struct _xmlDoc *)’}
  141 | int rb_st_foreach(st_table *, st_foreach_callback_func *, st_data_t);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_document.h:4,
                 from xml_document.c:1:
xml_document.c: In function ‘duplicate_document’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:330:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  330 |   if(rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &level) == 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:357:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  357 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "0*", &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c: In function ‘create_entity’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:436:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  436 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "14", &name, &type, &external_id, &system_id,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c: In function ‘canonicalize’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c:511:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  511 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "03", &mode, &incl_ns, &with_comments);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_document_fragment.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_document_fragment.h:4,
                 from xml_document_fragment.c:1:
xml_document_fragment.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document_fragment.c:17:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   17 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "1*", &document, &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_document_fragment.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_dtd.c
compiling xml_element_content.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_encoding_handler.c
compiling xml_entity_decl.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_entity_reference.h:4,
                 from xml_entity_reference.c:1:
xml_entity_reference.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_entity_reference.c:18:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
   18 |   rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "2*", &document, &name, &rest);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_entity_reference.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_io.c
xml_io.c: In function ‘io_read_callback’:
xml_io.c:20:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |   string = rb_rescue(read_check, (VALUE)args, read_failed, 0);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      VALUE (*)(VALUE *) {aka long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int *)}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:17: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE *)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int *)’}
 1987 | VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_io.c:20:47: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |   string = rb_rescue(read_check, (VALUE)args, read_failed, 0);
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                               |
      |                                               VALUE (*)(void) {aka long unsigned int (*)(void)}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:39: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(void)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(void)’}
 1987 | VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_io.c: In function ‘io_write_callback’:
xml_io.c:47:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   47 |   size = rb_rescue(write_check, (VALUE)args, write_failed, 0);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    |
      |                    VALUE (*)(VALUE *) {aka long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int *)}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:17: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE *)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int *)’}
 1987 | VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_io.c:47:46: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   47 |   size = rb_rescue(write_check, (VALUE)args, write_failed, 0);
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                              |
      |                                              VALUE (*)(void) {aka long unsigned int (*)(void)}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:39: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(void)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(void)’}
 1987 | VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_io.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
compiling xml_libxml2_hacks.c
compiling xml_namespace.c
compiling xml_node.c
xml_node.c: In function ‘reparent_node_with’:
xml_node.c:304:29: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘xmlFree’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  304 |       xmlFree(reparentee->ns->prefix);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
xml_node.c:304:29: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const xmlChar *’ {aka ‘const unsigned char *’}
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_node.h:4,
                 from xml_node.c:1:
xml_node.c: In function ‘duplicate_node’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_node.c:550:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  550 |   n_args = rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "02", &r_level, &r_new_parent_doc);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_node.c: In function ‘new’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2508:48: warning: cast discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]
 2508 |        (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars), (char *)fmt, varc)
      |                                                ^
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_node_set.h:4,
                 from xml_node_set.c:1:
xml_node_set.c: In function ‘init_xml_node_set’:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2799:117: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘rb_define_method0’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 2799 | #define rb_define_method(klass, mid, func, arity) rb_define_method_choose_prototypem3((arity),(func))((klass),(mid),(func),(arity));
      |                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~
      |                                                                                                                     |
      |                                                                                                                     VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE) {aka long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int)}
xml_node_set.c:479:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_define_method’
  479 |   rb_define_method(klass, "to_a", to_array, 0);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2148,
                 from /home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_node_set.h:4,
                 from xml_node_set.c:1:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2775:27: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int)’} but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(long unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’}
 2775 | RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL(rb_define_method, (2,3), (VALUE klass, const char *name), (klass, name))
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/intern.h:1042:82: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL_C’
 1042 |     __attribute__((__unused__,__weakref__(#def),__nonnull__ nonnull))static void defname(RB_UNWRAP_MACRO decl,VALUE(*func)funcargs,int arity);
      |                                                                                  ^~~~~~~
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/intern.h:1074:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL_1’
 1074 | RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL_1(def,nonnull,def##0 ,0 ,decl,vars,(VALUE)) \
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2775:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL’
 2775 | RB_METHOD_DEFINITION_DECL(rb_define_method, (2,3), (VALUE klass, const char *name), (klass, name))
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xml_node_set.c: At top level:
/home/xynyx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2340:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args0’
 2340 |         rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
xslt_stylesheet.c:141:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘rb_scan_args’
  141 |     rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "11", &xmldoc, &paramobj);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
At top level:
xslt_stylesheet.c:112:13: warning: ‘swallow_superfluous_xml_errors’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  112 | static void swallow_superfluous_xml_errors(void * userdata, xmlErrorPtr error, ...)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
current directory: /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:202: .sitearchdir.-.nokogiri.time] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/xynyx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nokogiri-1.10.9/gem_make.out
```